# __type and inheritance with WCFService

Tags: c#, json, wcf

```
    [DataContract]
    public abstract  class BusMessage
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "encoding")]
        public string Encoding { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public virtual MessageType Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            private set { _type = value; }
        }
    }

[DataContract]
public class BusTextMessage : BusMessage
{
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public override MessageType Type
    {
        get { return MessageType.Text; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "payload")]
    public string Payload { get; set; }
}




    [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(Helper))]
    public interface ICommunicationService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "/SendMessage")]
        string SendMessage(BusMessage jsonMessage);
    }
}
```

When I send request with Postman chrome, if I don't add __type as   "__type":"BusTextMessage:#TransportModels.Messages" the object won't be serialized properly because it doesn't know how to instantiate BusMessage class. I have already defined Type property which defines the type of message. Is there any possibility to override __type behaviour for example return proper implementation depending on Type property? I don't want anyone to put __type information to json manually so is there an option to edit json before deserialization and add __type property manually to json if it doesn't exist? For example I want to do something like this:

```
public void BeforeDeserialization(string json)
{
       if(json doesnt include __type)
       {
           if(json property type(my property) is MessageType.Text)
            add to json "__type":"BusTextMessage:#TransportModels.Messages"

       ///etc
       }
}
```

I Found this methods but it doesn't seem to be usable:

```
 [OnDeserializing()]
        internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the KnownType attribute to the BusMessage class.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(BusTextMessage)]
public class BusMessage
{
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: It is not answer to my question. In addition it's enough to add it in WCFService

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest solution I discovered. I configure MessageInspector and handle AfterReceiveRequest. Then I check message format(XML,JSON). If it is XML(for example sent from any WCF Client written in C#, WCF is configured to send everything with XML's) then I accept that message because field __type will be automatically inserted by WCF mechanism. Otherwise I Check if it is JSON, for example sent from external client. If it doesn't contain property "__type" I check my property Type and generate proper __type value. For example if my Type is equal to Text I add __type property BusTextMessage:#TransportModels.Messages and insert it into JSON and then recreate the message. I couldn't find quicker and easier solution and it seems to be working. Handling AfterReceiveRequest I found at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-REST-Message-Inspector-c4b6790b.

```
  public class MessageTypeInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
   {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext                 instanceContext)
        {
           RecreateMessage(ref request);
            return null;
        }
   }





private void RecreateMessage(ref Message message)
        {
            WebContentFormat messageFormat = this.GetMessageContentFormat(message);
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = null;
            switch (messageFormat)
            {
                case WebContentFormat.Default:
                case WebContentFormat.Xml:
                    writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms);
                    break;
                case WebContentFormat.Json:
                    writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(ms);
                    break;
                case WebContentFormat.Raw:
                   this.ReadRawBody(ref message);
                    break;
            }

            message.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

            if (messageFormat == WebContentFormat.Json && !messageBody.Contains("__type"))
                messageBody = AddTypeField(messageBody);

            ms.Position = 0;


            ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

            XmlDictionaryReader reader = messageFormat == WebContentFormat.Json ?
                JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max) :
                XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);

            Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
            newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(message.Properties);
            message = newMessage;

        }

 private WebContentFormat GetMessageContentFormat(Message message)
        {
            WebContentFormat format = WebContentFormat.Default;
            if (message.Properties.ContainsKey(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name))
            {
                WebBodyFormatMessageProperty bodyFormat;
                bodyFormat = (WebBodyFormatMessageProperty)message.Properties[WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name];
                format = bodyFormat.Format;
            }

            return format;
        }

private string AddTypeField(string jsonReply)
        {
            var typeRegex = new Regex("\"type\":(?<number>[0-9]*)");

            Match match = typeRegex.Match(jsonReply);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                int number = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["number"].Value);
                var type = (MessageType)number;
                var nameFormat = string.Format("Bus{0}Message", type);
                string format = string.Format("\"__type\":\"{0}:#TransportModels.Messages\"", nameFormat);
                jsonReply = "{" + string.Format("{0},{1}", format, jsonReply.Substring(1));
                return jsonReply;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong message type.");
            }
        }
```